# How can I export a video of a wind-blown object shot by a moving camera?

Tags: rendering, animation, camera, cloth-simulation, force-fields

How can I export a video of a wind-blown object shot by a moving camera?

The objects I prepared is several papers looking objects. They are inside the square wire frame and constantly blown by a wind and turbulence (Force Field)
I made them by referencing this nice tutorial on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Nx38iwliZI

I also prepared a camera which moves around the objects. And I wanted to make a short movie clip. But when I rendered this scene as a movie (H264), the camera follows the pass but the papers are not moving. And the image I get is just like the camera moving around the papers that frozen in the air.

Could you please advice me what I missed?
Is there any other step I need to do before rendering movie?

Thank you.

---

Screenshot

I'm hiding extra objects that doesn't related to my question. All the paper objects are inside of the wire frame. If I play the animation, they move. But they don't move once I render it as a movie clip. Only the camera does move.

Image 01: looking down the whole situation (at the point of frame "0")
[image]

Image 02: get closer (at the point of frame "500")
[image]

Image 03: Paper objects at frame "0"
[image]

Image 04: Paper objects at frame "500"
[image]

Comment: Please add screenshots from your own file. We have no idea what you missed

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added some screenshot here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233006/how-can-i-export-a-video-of-a-wind-blown-object-shot-by-a-moving-camera-2

Comment: no need to repost. You can edit your question (and should in this case)

Comment: Meanwhile, looking at the screenshots (but with a sleepy mind), I am wondering if there is a modifier/constraint that has different render settings than viewport settings, or render display is turned off.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to bake the simulation before you render it?

Comment: I would like to thank the two respondents. I'll reaffirm the rendering settings and the need for bake. I don't fully understand what specifically I should do yet. But somehow I can imagine what I should do. Thanks for your kind help. (Accurate guess even with a sleepy mind!)