# How can I export a video of a wind-blown object shot by a moving camera? (2)

Tags: animation, camera, cloth-simulation, force-fields

How can I export a video of a wind-blown object shot by a moving camera?

The objects I prepared is several papers looking objects. They are inside the square wire frame and constantly blown by a wind and turbulence (Force Field) I made them by referencing this nice tutorial on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Nx38iwliZI

I also prepared a camera which moves around the objects. And I wanted to make a short movie clip. But when I rendered this scene as a movie (H264), the camera follows the pass but the papers are not moving. And the image I get is just like the camera moving around the papers that frozen in the air.

Could you please advice me what I missed? Is there any other step I need to do before rendering movie?

Thank you.

---

In addition to the question,I've attached a screenshot.

I'm hiding extra objects that doesn't related to my question.
All the paper objects are inside of the wire frame. If I play the animation, they move. But they don't move once I render it as a movie clip. Only the camera does move.

Image 01: looking down the whole situation (at the point of frame "0")
[image]

Image 02: get closer (at the point of frame "500")
[image]

Image 03: Paper objects at frame "0"
[image]

Image 04: Paper objects at frame "500"
[image]

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. Instead, edit your first question.

Comment: I didn't know where I can edit it, but I found it after you pointed out. sorry. thank you for letting me know.